# Wrap wrapped TMENU Elements

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I want to wrap some wrapped li Elements in Typo3 with TS for the NO-State, not for ACT.
I have try some differents ways, but nothing is functional.

For example, i want the following HTML-Code

```
<div class="flyoutMetaLanguageSelection" id="metaLanguage">
  <h3>Austria</h3>
  <ul style="display:none;" class="metaNavList">
    <li><a href="#">German</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Spain</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">USA</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is the Typo3 BE Structure for this points:

```
[metalanguages]-level 1
 |- German
 |- Spain
 |- Austria
 |- USA
```

The active Point, will wrap with a  element and set to the top of all other elements.

And this is my TypoScript

```
lib.MetaNavigationCountrySelectFields = HMENU
lib.MetaNavigationCountrySelectFields{
    special = directory
    special.value = 1

    1 = TMENU
    1{
        noBlur = 1
        expAll = 1
        NO{
            wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
            wrapItemAndSub.insertData = 1
           #allWrap = <ul class="metaNavList" style="display:none;">|</ul>
            allStdWrap.insertData = 1
        }
        #NO.stdWrap.outerWrap.override  = <ul>|</ul>
        #NO.wrapItem = <ul class="metaNavList" style="display:block;">|</ul>

        ACT <. NO
        ACT = 1
        ACT{
            wrapItemAndSub = <h3>|</h3>
            wrapItemAndSub.insertData = 1
            doNotLinkIt = 1
        }
        RO <. ACT
    }
}
```

I hope everyone can help me....and sorry for my "bad english" ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can't pick out one menu item and place it outside the menu.

I would create a COA and insert the active item on top.

```
temp.menu = COA
temp.menu {
  10 = TMENU
  // make a Tmenu that just shows the active item 
  10.wrap = <h3>|</h3>
  20 = TMENU
  20.noBlur = 1
  20.wrap = <ul>|</ul>
  // here you can hide the active item
}
```

Also: According to this http://jweiland.net/typo3/typoscript/wrap-moeglichkeiten-und-hierarchie-in-menues.html, `wrapItemAndSub` is the outermost wrap in a menu.

And btw: you have set `insertData`, but you're not using it.